Byte marks in a ASP.NET Core razor view
When I run my app and inspect my HTML in the browser, I see this thing:

It doesn't appear in my .cshtml file and it really messes up with my layout(it's the cause for the margin between the heading and the footer). After some research, I found out it's called a "byte order mark" and it's something hidden in the file. I tried copying the code, deleting the file, creating it again, and pasting the code and the byte order mark is somehow still there. It only happens in this .cshtml file for no apparent reason.  What is the easiest way to remove it and why did it appear in the first place?
